# How to find the next SpellLocal

Tags: search, cursor-motions, spell-checking

I am curious to know how I can find the next instance of a SpellLocal mistake (either by a motion key or via a search command) in vim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is modify the `]s` and `[s` motions to skip over `SpellBad` highlighted words. This is actually not very hard. With the [`spellbadword()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#spellbadword%28%29) function we can get information about the spell status of the current word:

Example outputs of `:echo spellbadword()`:

- test: `['', '']`
- behavior (with en-gb locale): `['behavior', 'local']`
- qwe: `['qwe', 'bad']`

So what we need to make is a mapping which:

1. Runs `]s`.
2. Checks if the word under the cursor has the status `local`.
3. If so, stop.
4. If the cursor position is unchanged, there are no more misspelled words and we stop.
5. All else: go to the next word and back to 1.

And here is exactly such a function:

```
fun! SpellLocal() abort
    let l:start_pos = getpos('.')

    while 1
        " Store the cursor position
        let l:cursor = getpos('.')

        " Run ]s
        normal ]s

        " The cursor position hasn't changed, this means ]s didn't find
        " anything else.
        if getpos('.') == l:cursor
            " Restore cursor position to match default ]s behaviour
            call setpos('.', l:start_pos)
            break
        endif

        " We found a SpellLocal; stop.
        if spellbadword()[1] == 'local'
            break
        " Something else; continue to next word
        else
            normal w
        endif
    endwhile
endfun

nnoremap <silent> <Leader>]s :call SpellLocal()<CR>
```

You can expand this by passing an argument which specifies the direction (`]s` or `[s`). This is left as an exercise for the reader :-)

Answer (score 4):

You could try [SrchRplcHiGrp.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/SrchRplcHiGrp.vim): this plugin creates a command `SRSearch` which allows to search for the occurrences of an highlight group. As `hl-SpellLocal` is an highlight group that should do the trick.

To use it you'll have to find a word highlighted as a SpellLocal error, put your cursor on this word and use `SRChooseHiGrp` to select the group you're looking for. Then you can use `SRSearch` to go to the next word of the group.

Comment: Sounds like it should work, but it doesn't (at least for me). `SRChooseHiGrp` does not select the correct group. However, this can be overcome by `SRChooseHiGrp 31`. However, afterwards `SRSearch` finds nothing. You can check this (unexpected behavior) with  `SRChooseHiGrp 28` (searching for bad spelling mistakes).

Comment: @Fabian: Indeed as I don't usually have spelling enabled I tested the plugin with some other highlighting groups (which worked) but after further investigations this doesn't find words in SpellBad... I suspect a bug in the plugin, I'll try to look at it and edit the answer if I find something.

Answer (score 1):

For navigating along the different spell mistakes, you can use the [`\[s`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/spell.html#]s) and [`\]s`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/spell.html#[s) motions, which move to the previous and next mistake.

See [`:h spell-quickstart`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/spell.html) for an introduction on how to use spell.

Comment: I understand. However, I am interested to only find the SpellLocal mistakes. There is the motion key ]S which only cares about the SpellBad mistakes.  How to do the analog for the SpellLocal mistakes?

Comment: I see, but from the reading I have of the documentation, I don't see anything related to it.